# Sublime Text Build in an external window

Tags: sublimetext2

Is there a way to create a build command in Sublime Text that opens a new external window (terminal/cmd.exe)? Everything I try gets captured to the built-in output window.

I tried:

```
{
   "cmd": ["ruby", "$file"],
   "target": "cmd.exe",
   "file_regex": "rb$",
   "selector": "source.rb"
}
```

But nothing happened

Answer (score 2):

The following works for Windows (I've tested it on XP and 7):

```json
{
    "cmd": ["start", "cmd", "/k", "c:/ruby193/ruby.exe", "$file"],
    "selector": "source.ruby",
    "shell": true,
    "working_dir": "$file_dir"
}
```

Save it as `Packages/User/Ruby_cmd.sublime-build` (you may need to alter the path to the Ruby executable depending on your system), select `Tools -> Build System -> Ruby_cmd`, and build with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>.

`start` does what it says it does, start a new process independent of Sublime Text. `cmd` is `cmd.exe`, the Windows command-line interpreter. The `/k` flag keeps the window open (at a new command prompt) after your program has run, allowing you to examine its output, look at tracebacks, run additional commands, etc.

Answer (score 1):

May be you will find this solution helpful:
https://github.com/rctay/sublime-text-2-buildview

(transfers build output in the separate sublime tab, you can then do with it whatever you want)